# SQL Server : Nested Cursor not responding

Tags: sql-server, cursor

I have the following cursor, trying to update records in a table to prep for an export into WooCommerce. They are variable products, so trying to update all product records with the proper attribute lists. I am doing it one attribute type at a time. When I run it it gets to where I am trying to create the string of attribute values and it hangs up. My goal is to loop through every product and then loop through that product's attributes to create a string. then update the record and move onto the next product.

```
DECLARE @id INT, @prodLoop INT, @attLoop INT
DECLARE @attrString char(8000)
DECLARE @getid CURSOR

SET @getid = CURSOR FOR
SELECT woo_export.prevProdID
FROM   woo_export
WHERE woo_export.prevProdID = 1174

OPEN @getid
FETCH NEXT
FROM @getid INTO @id

SET @prodLoop = @@FETCH_STATUS

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0

    BEGIN

--      CREATE CURSOR FOR ALL ATTRIBUTES
        DECLARE @attrName char(8000)
        DECLARE @getAtts CURSOR

        SET @getAtts = CURSOR FOR
        SELECT      o.optionDescription
        FROM        dbo.ProductOptionType t
                    INNER JOIN dbo.ProductOption o 
                        ON (t.optionTypeID = o.optionTypeID)
                    INNER JOIN dbo.ProductItem2Option oi 
                        ON (o.optionID = oi.optionID)
                    INNER JOIN dbo.ProductItem i 
                        ON (i.itemID = oi.itemID)
        WHERE       i.productID = @id
        AND     i.isActive = 1
        AND     t.optionTypeID = 1 


        OPEN @getAtts
        FETCH NEXT
        FROM @getAtts INTO @attrName

        WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0

            BEGIN
--          CREATE STRING OF ATTRIBUTES

            SELECT @attrString = CONCAT(@attrString,', ', @attrName);

            FETCH NEXT
            FROM @getAtts INTO @attrName

            END

--      REMOVE INITIAL COMMA AND SPACE FROM STRING
        SELECT @attrString = SUBSTRING(@attrString, 3, LEN(@attrString)-2)

--      UPDATE WOO EXPORT PRODUCT WITH ATTRIBUTES WHERE THEY HAVE THIS ATTRIBUTE
        IF LEN(@attrString) > 0
            BEGIN

            UPDATE  woo_export 
            SET     attribute_1_name = 'Color', attribute_1_value = @attrString
            WHERE   prevProdID = @id

            END 

        SELECT @attrName = '';

        CLOSE @getAtts
        DEALLOCATE @getAtts

        FETCH NEXT
        FROM @getid INTO @id


    END

CLOSE @getid
DEALLOCATE @getid
```

Comment: Can you provide some example data - input and expected output? First problem with your code are the `@prodLoop` and `@attLoop` variables. You need to set them in each iteration of the cursor so they get the latest value of `@@FETCH_STATUS`. That would be one reason of this code running into infinite loop.

Comment: I swapped back @@Fetch_Status for the variables and the query runs (not a loop - THANKS). However now the inner loop just adds the first record to the @attrString variable and then breaks out. For my test case I know there should be three records. I had added the variables for the the status because I thought they might conflict. how can i iterate the variable to the correct fetch_status?

Comment: When I run it on the whole dataset, not just a specific productiID, it adds the same single record to every product after the initial product that had a listing. So the inner loop gets its first record and then never reloads the inner cursor.

Comment: I have narrowed it down to the line
SELECT @attrString = CONCAT(@attrString,', ', @attrName);
is not actually creating the string. it adds the first value then never adds the rest, even though the cursor changes the attrName value.  What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: It is really difficult to help without any sample data. Can you post some sample data (preferably in [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a6c585/1)) and that way it will be much easier for someone to understand and help.